# Error message "Could not find stored procedure" when executing stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure to retrieve employee details from a SQL Server database. It was working fine on the staging server.

I just changed the connection string. I have pointed it at my local SQL Server. Connection string is proper. I am getting error near

```
cmd.executenonquery()
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
public EmployeeDetail GetClientData(int? clientId, string empId, string citizenId, string connectingString)
{
    string constring = connectingString;

    EmployeeDetail objclValues = new EmployeeDetail();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_Corporate_Employee_Get_Info_for_KYC", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            if (clientId == null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorporateID", DBNull.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorporateID", clientId);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(empId))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", DBNull.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", empId);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(citizenId))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenId", DBNull.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenId", citizenId);
            }

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CorporateName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpFullName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nationality", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RetEmpId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RetCitizenID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ResponseCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 2);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ResponseMessage", SqlDbType.VarChar, 70);

            cmd.Parameters["@CorporateName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters["@EmpFullName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters["@Nationality"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters["@RetEmpId"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters["@RetCitizenID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters["@ResponseCode"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters["@ResponseMessage"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            objclValues.ClientName = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@CorporateName"].Value.ToString());
            objclValues.EmpName = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@EmpFullName"].Value.ToString());
            objclValues.Nationality = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@Nationality"].Value.ToString());
            objclValues.RetEmpId = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@RetEmpId"].Value.ToString());
            objclValues.RetCitizenID = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@RetCitizenID"].Value.ToString());
            objclValues.ResponseCode = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@ResponseCode"].Value.ToString());
            objclValues.ResponseMessage = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@ResponseMessage"].Value.ToString());
            objclValues.clientId = clientId.GetValueOrDefault(0);
            objclValues.EmpId = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@RetEmpId"].Value.ToString());
            objclValues.EmpCitizenId = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@RetCitizenID"].Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    return objclValues;
}
```

Connection strings are below.

```
<!--<add key="SPConnectionstring" value="Data Source=192.168.0.210;Initial Catalog=Test_C3CKYC;UID=sa;Password=123@root" />-->
<add key="SPConnectionstring" 
     value="Data Source=aufbkmjvl28\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=C3KYC;persist security info=True;UID=sa;Password=root@123" />
```

Above, commented out section will work correctly.

May I know why I am getting this error? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried with schema at the beginning e.g. `dbo`? It seems that you made mistake somewhere else because code looks correct.

Comment: I am able to access other tables(Normal tables other than SP's)

Comment: Well - considering you mention the only thing you've changed is the connectionstring - do you have the procedure on the database?

Comment: yes i have procedure in Db. This is my connectionstring.  <!--<add key="SPConnectionstring" value="Data Source=192.168.0.210;Initial Catalog=Test_C3CKYC;UID=sa;Password=123@root" />-->
    <add key="SPConnectionstring" value="Data Source=aufbkmjvl28\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=C3KYC;persist security info=True;UID=sa;Password=root@123" />  Here commented stored procedure works correctly.

Comment: Is that user account has access to that stored procedure?

Comment: How to check that access?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole, what do you mean by commented section working properly and is second connection string pointed local db or what?

Comment: the second pointed to local.It is not working. First pointed to staginag and it is working fine.

Comment: That database names look different.  Is the database name C3KYC or Test_C3CKYC?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

to this:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

if you want to run a stored procedure ...

Comment: @marc_s Please do you think you could take a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197865/mssql-is-there-any-performance-penalty-for-wrapping-a-select-query-in-a-transa